# "op.student( , ) is not JSON serializable" in Odoo 10

Tags: python, json

I want to return data from python to javascript. I am calling function `get_students_in_a_class` in my js file. In which I want all the data which I am returning from python code in Odoo 10

Python code

```
@api.model
def get_students_in_a_class(self):
    _logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    # _logger.info('Class id'  + repr(val.x_class_id) )
    parents = self.env['parents'].search([('partner_id','=', self.env.user.partner_id.id)])
    _logger.info('Parents ' + repr(parents))

    sessions = []
    classes = []
    students = []

    for parent in parents:
         students = self.env['op.student'].search([('parents_ids','=', parent.id)])
         _logger.info('Students ' + repr(students))

         for student in students:
            classes = self.env['x_classes'].search([('id','=', student.x_class_id.id)])
            _logger.info('Classes ' + repr(classes))

            for clas in classes:
                sessions = self.env['sessions'].search([('class_id','=',clas.id)])
                _logger.info('Sessions ' + repr(sessions))

    d = dict()
    d['Classes'] = classes
    d['Sessions'] = sessions
    d['Students'] = students
    _logger.info('Data-->> ' + repr(d))
    return d
```

Js code

```
 odoo.define('javascript_module.demo', function(require){
 "use strict"

 var model = require('web.Model');
 var studentModel = new  model('op.student');

 var data = studentModel.call('get_students_in_a_class')
 console.log('data--->>>>>>>', JSON.stringify(data));

})
```

But it is showing error

```
Server application error 
{"message":"Odoo Server Error","code":200,"data":{"debug":"Traceback (most r 
recent call last):\n  File \"E:\\Oddo\\Odoo 10.0\\server\\odoo\\http.py\", 
line 640, in _handle_exception\n  File \"E:\\Oddo\\Odoo 
10.0\\server\\odoo\\http.py\", line 691, in dispatch\n  File 
\"E:\\Oddo\\Odoo 10.0\\server\\odoo\\http.py\", line 629, in 
_json_response\n  File \"json\\__init__.pyc\", line 244, in dumps\n  File 
\"json\\encoder.pyc\", line 207, in encode\n  File \"json\\encoder.pyc\", 
line 270, in iterencode\n  File \"json\\encoder.pyc\", line 184, in 
default\nTypeError: op.student(113, 115) is not JSON 
serializable\n","exception_type":"internal_error","message":"op.student(113, 
115) is not JSON serializable","name":"exceptions.TypeError","arguments":
["op.student(113, 115) is not JSON serializable"]}}
```

Comment: so, what does the JSON data look like?

Comment: @JaromandaX  {'id': student_id, "name": Student Name, "class_id": class_id, "session" : [{"session_id" : Sessions Id , 'session_name' : Sessions Name }]} I want this type of JSON Data